# Error in CASE statement

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

Problem in Writing the CASE statement. Please HELP

```
insert into CDR(rts,smscid,count,statusflag,operator,identifier)
     select trunc(rts),smscid,statusflag,operator, 
     (case when smscid='BPL-MUM' and operator='BPL' and  is_number(replace(replace(replace(senderid, 'DM-',''), 'LM-',''),'BT-',''))=0 THEN "LOOP TRANSACTIONAL"
          when smscid='BPL-MUM' and operator!='BPL' and  is_number(replace(replace(replace(senderid, 'DM-',''), 'LM-',''),'BT-',''))=0 THEN "NONLOOP TRANSACTIONAL"
          When Smscid='BPL-MUM' And Operator='BPL' And  Is_Number(Replace(Replace(Replace(Senderid, 'DM-',''), 'LM-',''),'BT-',''))!=0 THEN "LOOP PROMOTIONAL"
          when smscid='BPL-MUM' and operator!='BPL' and  is_number(replace(replace(replace(senderid, 'DM-',''), 'LM-',''),'BT-',''))!=0 THEN  "NONLOOP PROMOTIONAL" 
          END),sum(count)    
      From Mis_Summary_Dn  Where Rts Between '26-dec-2012' And '27-dec-2012' And Statusflag='SUCCESS' Group By Trunc(Rts),Smscid,Statusflag,Operator;
```

I am Getting error like

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NONLOOP PROMOTIONAL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your strings in single quotes, not double quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers

```
'NONLOOP PROMOTIONAL'
```